# Einstein Synced events are not events - what are they?

Tags: event, einstein

We have Einstein syncing events from our work google account into SF calendar.

However, when these events are created, they are different from a regular event created in SF.

This event was created in Google, and synced:
[image]

While this event was created in SF:
[image]

Also, if running a report on events, the synced one does not show up at all.

I don't have any record types on events, so what is the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to check the 'Only Show Events That Are Salesforce Records' setting under the Settings tab in the Einstein Activity Capture admin settings. If this is turned off then the events might not be available in standard reporting.

There are a few settings mentioned under the 'Activity Timeline' header of this page that might help: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.aac_event_considerations.htm&type=5